# How to import a list from within a function into another python module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

I've got 2 files. File 1 has a function and within it, a list. I'm trying to print the contents of that list in File2, however, I'm getting name errors?

Below is File1 where the function is kept, the list I'm trying to access in file 2 is called product.

```py
def news_articles():
    search_metric = {
        "q": "covid",
        "apiKey": "d5da78e207f94fdc8eecd3530acf4edb"
    }
    base_url = "https://newsapi.org/v2/everything?"

    # fetching data in json format
    res = requests.get(base_url, params=search_metric)
    open_news = res.json()

    # getting all articles in a string article
    article = open_news["articles"]

    # empty list which will
    # contain all trending news
    global product
    product = []

    for s in article:
        product.append(s["title"])
```

In file2, I'm just trying to import the module and print(product)

Comment: Share some code please, from File1 and File 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to make `product` list global. Try avoid making your functions depend on global variables. Most programmers found it a [bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19158339/13944524).

All you have to do is return `product` list from the `news_articles()` function. Then in your `file2` you can simply print the result of that function which is the `product` list.

```
import file1
print(file1.news_articles())
```